# Add CSS Class to SharePoint Drop down Field using JQuery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, jquery

i want to add css class to choice drop down filed using jquery below is code.

```
$("input[title='fieldname']").attr('class', 'form-control')
```

But somehow it is not working.

can anyone help me regarding this

Comment: Where you hvae Added "form-control" Class in sharepoint ?

Comment: it is in my css file

Comment: Are you using `<select>` as drop down or `<input>` ?

Comment: Might be it is SharePoint control  @Yayati.

Comment: @Yayati i am using select as dropdown

Comment: then try this one `$("select[title='fieldname']").attr('class', 'form-control')`

Comment: it is choice field and it shown render as dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You are using `input` instead of `select` in your script.
Try following script:

```
$("select[title='fieldname']").attr('class', 'form-control')
```

Comment: `addClass('form-control')` is cleaner than adding the class attribute yourself.

Comment: Yes, I agree. `addClass('form-control')` method add another class to the element wherease `.attr('class', 'form-control')` will replace any class attached to the element with the specified one.